# WINE "wine: could not load ntdll.so: (null)" on ArchLinux ARM

Tags: arch-linux, wine, 64bit, arm64

Since I'm running an ARM system, I installed Arch in a x86_64 chroot, then installed WINE. However, running `wincfg` gave `wine: could not load ntdll.so: (null)`. I assumed that it meant that WINE couldn't find the file, so then I did `WINEDLLPATH=/usr/lib32/wine/i386-unix winecfg`. However, that gave `wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32`. I'm assuming that WINE somehow knows this is an ARM system and won't allow it to run. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a lot of trial and error, I got it to work with

```
WINEDLLPATH=/usr/lib/wine/x86_64-unix wine64
```

It seems that I have a 64 bit `.wine`, which is why it wouldn't accept the others. No idea why it didn't find the DLL's by itself.

EDIT: It also seemed that I needed to copy the `qemu-*` into the guest.